# Concatenate strings with delimeter in for loop in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

Adding comma creates a space instead of appending comma.

Note: Value of `$1` is `s,v,h`

```
declare -A handles
handles["s"]="test1"
handles["v"]="test2"
handles["h"]="test3"

IFS=',' list=($1)
for item in "${list[@]}"; do
        result+=",${handles["$item"]}"
done

echo -e $result
```

Output: `test1 test2 test3`

Expected: `test1,test2,test3`

Comment: @markp-fuso Value of `$1` is `s,v,h`

Comment: `IFS=',' list=($1)` is not executing the `list` assignment with IFS set in its environment.  Instead, it is equivalent to `IFS=','; list=($1);`, thus acting as two assignments.  I would argue the core problem is the lack of quotes in the echo, which should be `echo -e "$result"`, but resetting IFS to a reasonable value is certainly a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

One idea to get around the issues with clobbering `IFS`, and eliminating unwanted commas from `$result`, ...

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

declare -A handles
handles["s"]="test1"
handles["v"]="test2"
handles["h"]="test3"
handles["a b c"]="test 4"

mapfile -t list < <(tr ',' '\n' <<< "$1")     # to handle white space in fields

unset pfx

for item in "${list[@]}"
do
    handle="${handles[$item]}"

    # only append if non-empty
    [ -n "${handle}" ] && result+="${pfx}${handle}" && pfx=','
done

echo -e "${result}"

$ script.sh 's,v,h'
test1,test2,test3

$ script.sh 'a b c,s,v,h'
test 4,test1,test2,test3

$ script.sh 'd e f,s,v,h'
test1,test2,test3

$ script.sh 'x,y,z,s,v,h,a,b,c'
test1,test2,test3
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to temporarily assign `IFS` to "," not to affect
the following codes. Then you can combine it with `read` command as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A handles=(
    ["s"]="test1"
    ["v"]="test2"
    ["h"]="test3"
)

IFS=',' read -r -a list <<< "$1"
for item in "${list[@]}"; do
    ary+=( "${handles["$item"]}" )
done

result=$(IFS=','; echo "${ary[*]}")
echo "$result"
```

- The `for` loop assigns the array `ary` to the values of the associative array `handles` keyed by the elements of `list`.
- The command `echo "${ary[*]}"` concatenates the array `ary` with the delimiter `,`. It is executed in the subshell without modifying `IFS` in the foreground process.

Answer (score 1):

The `IFS` is the problem:

```
> x=",a" && x+=",b" && x+=",c" && echo $x
,a,b,c 
> IFS="," && x=",a" && x+=",b" && x+=",c" && echo $x
 a b c
```

Just add `IFS=""` before the `echo` or use `echo -e "$result"` and it will work.

Comment: This is one way to see it. From my perspective, the unquoted `$result` is the problem and not `IFS`.